# AFNetworking Store Credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am very new to AFNetworking. I was using ASIHTTPRequest which I found a lot easier, but heard its no good.

Now I am trying to redo everything I did with ASIHTTPRequest with AFNetworking. I created a method to login to an API:

```
-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
{


   __block BOOL isLoggedIn;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[@"losanihomes" stringByAppendingString:user]
                                                        password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]];



    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        isLoggedIn = YES;


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        isLoggedIn = NO;

    }];


    [operation start];
    return isLoggedIn;
}
```

Now my question is how do I store these credentials and then reuse them? in ASIHTTPRequest it would store the credentials automatically.

Comment: I noticed you are using `NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone`, which implies you will have to provide the credentials every time. There are [other options available](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLCredentialPersistence).

Comment: I gonna use `NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession` so now when I call that url again `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];` I dont need the creds anymore?

Comment: Not really sure. I haven't used NSURLCredential a whole lot. But as I understand it, sessions are based on when the app launched. You will have to test it, or hopefully someone else will answer.

Comment: I tried to make another call without creds and I got an authorized error

Comment: Seems reasonable if the webservice requires credentials.